# Odd EE Installation issue

Tags: ee1

I'm installing ee1.6.8 on WAMP. I've done this many many times, I use it for testing before i attempt the real deal on the live servers. I've done this on all versions between 1.6.8 - 2.5.5 and they always always worked.

However this time, EE's installation refuses to install because it thinks it does not have the privileges to INSERT/DELETE etc... when in fact it absolutely does. I'm using the root/NO account which has ALL PRIVILEGES.

I've tried via localhost and 127.0.0.1 and it just keeps failing. This is on WAMP 2.2

Any ideas?

==== UPDATE ====

I just tried installing 1.6.9, 1.7.2 and 2.5.5 and both worked smoothly. So it appears that for whatever reason 1.6.X does NOT like wamp 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded mysql addon for wamp with mysql 5.1.41 and told wamp to use it instead. Once that change was made ee168 and ee169 installed flawlessly. I guess it was a mysql compatibility issue.